# EJS doesn't escape characters

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have a Node JS server querying MongoDB, and then render the returns to an EJS template:
`res.render('graphFabric.ejs', {'iBeacons':[(beacon)]});`.
When I try to recover the JSON from my template using 
`<%=iBeacons%>`
, `'` (single quotes) appear as `&#39`;
For example: `udid: &#39;b9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d&#39;,`
How is it possible to fix this issue since it breaks my JSON structure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured from https://github.com/tj/ejs/tree/0.8.3#features that I was using:
`Escapes html by default with <%= code %>` when I should have used 
`Unescaped buffering with <%- code %>`

**Replacing `=` with `-` fixed the problem