# Optional Character in Form Input Text Pattern

Tags: html, node.js, forms, input, ejs

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, please point me in that direction.

Using Node and EJS, I have a form field for capturing the name of a brewery, this comes via an API...

```
<label>Brewery</label><br>
<input id="formBreweryName" class="form-control" type="text" name="breweryname" ><br>
<label>Beer Name</label><br>
<input id="formBeerName" class="form-control" type="text" name="beername" >
```

Here's the ejs that both displays the brewery name in a `<ul>` and contains the `onclick` handler for populating the form...

```
 <ul>
    <% BeerList.forEach(function(objsofbeer){ %>
       <li>
          <a onclick="addFormText( '<%= objsofbeer.brewery.brewery_name %>','<%= objsofbeer.beer.beer_name %>')">
          <span><%= objsofbeer.brewery.brewery_name %></span><br>
          <span><%= objsofbeer.beer.beer_name %></span><br>      
          </a>
       </li>
</ul>
```

And the javascript for porting the brewery name up to the form...

```
var addFormText = function( breweryName, beerName) {
    document.getElementById('formBreweryName').value = breweryName;
    document.getElementById('formBeerName').value = beerName;
      }
```

the API passes me a brewery name like so...

```
brewery_name: 'Reuben\'s Brews',
```

I added the beer name in the code above for good measure.

**The Issue**

When there is an apostrophe in the brewery name, the brewery name will not show in the appropriate form field, BUT the brewery name does show in the  section.

For most examples, the brewery name does not have an apostrophe. So the API brewery name shows up in the form field as expected. But as in the example above, the brewery name has an apostrophe, so the name will not show up in my form field.

I am hoping there is a non-javascript, pattern attribute solution that will let me **optionally include apostrophes** (or other unforeseen special characters) in the text. If not, then I'm open to javascript or other suggestions.

I see many examples of 'use pattern to *exclude* certain characters' or 'use pattern to force users to only *use this given text pattern*'. But I don't see anything that would allow for the **optional inclusion** of a character like an apostrophe (or any other optional inclusion of special characters).

If it seems like this is an issue beyond my form input field, I am happy to share more of my coding.

Comment: pls show how you set the input. Are you using JQuery, or angular or what?

Comment: Thanks Francesco, I added all the code I think you need, please let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but i think the problem is that you need a double escape character before the accent, one for the ejs on the server and one for the js on the browser. Can you try using <%- instead of <%= ([EJS doesn't escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164291/ejs-doesnt-escape-characters)).
Sorry i never used ejs... other try, very ugly...:

```
<ul>
<% BeerList.forEach(function(objsofbeer){ %>
<%   objsofbeer.brewery.brewery_name = objsofbeer.brewery.brewery_name.replace("'","\\'"); %>
<%   objsofbeer.beer.beer_name = objsofbeer.beer.beer_name.replace("'","\\'"); %>
   <li>
      <a onclick="addFormText( '<%= objsofbeer.brewery.brewery_name %>','<%= objsofbeer.beer.beer_name %>')">
      <span><%= objsofbeer.brewery.brewery_name %></span><br>
      <span><%= objsofbeer.beer.beer_name %></span><br>      
      </a>
   </li>
```

or try playng with ` character instead " or '

Comment: Thanks Francesco, I've been out of town so haven't had a chance to try this. I'll follow-up soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Francesco, I have tried all of your suggestions above (I was hoping that <%- versus <%= would do it), but none of them work.

Comment: what is the output of <%= objsofbeer.beer.beer_name.replace('\'','\\\'') %>?

Comment: It throws the error `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` and when I'm looking at the code in my code editor `<a onclick="addFormText( '<%= objsofbeer.beer.brewery_name.replace('\'','\\\'') %>','<%- objsofbeer.beer.beer_name %>'`, it shows red underline errors under the first escape backslash and subsequent ejs markings like `%>` and `<%`. So it's showing errors in the editor even before I run this code and then running it confirms the errors.

Comment: i edited the answer... if this do not work, try to do the same thing to the BeerList object before the rendering of the ejs.